# CKEditor5 Balloon Build - Clipboard items for toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I am upgrading from CKEditor4 to CKEditor5. I want to have the same toolbar configuration we had, but I can't figure out how to add the Clipboard features (copy, cut, paste, etc.).

I'm trying to add them to the ckeditor5-build-balloon build. I've tried a few different things:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard
```

I read something that implied the *Essentials* plugin includes the clipboard features, but I'm adding it to the build-config.js (@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard) just in case...

I can't find any examples that show how to add the clipboard tools to the toolbar. Based on the v4 config, I'm trying this setup:

```
config: {
        toolbar: {
            items: [
                'copy',
                'cut',
                'paste',
            ]
        },
```

I've also tried specifying the toolbar options in my instance usage of BalloonEditor:

```
BalloonEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        toolbar: [ 'copy', 'cut', 'paste' ]
...
```

But the toolbar doesn't ever have any of the clipboard features. I understand there is a new "minimalist" approach to the new version and the keyboard shortcuts of CTRL+C/V are widely understood. But it seems like you should be able to include them, right?

Answer (score 2):

The `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard` doesn't offer copy, cut and paste buttons. You're right that the main reason is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C/V/X</kbd> are widely known. But there are also other reasons – these buttons take precious space in the toolbar and... you couldn't paste using such a button anyway.

E.g., check out what CKEditor 4 will do if you'll trigger the paste's button action (you can actually see that there's no such a button in the toolbar too; I had to trigger this from the console):

[image: CKEditor 4 displays a notification that you cannot paste by using the paste button and you should use Ctrl+V instead]

That's because the access to the clipboard is limited for security reasons. You can programmatically copy/cut things (put content into the clipboard), but you can't paste. Otherwise, every website could read your copied data. Not fun.

Anyway, copy/cut are doable. And you can display some alert when the user presses the paste button. If you want that, then you'll need to implement a simple plugin:

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';

import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';

import ButtonView from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/button/buttonview';

function ClipboardButtons( editor ) {
    addButton( 'copy', 'Copy' );
    addButton( 'cut', 'Cut' );
    addButton( 'paste', 'Paste' );

    function addButton( action, label ) {
        editor.ui.componentFactory.add( action, locale => {
            const view = new ButtonView( locale );

            view.set( {
                label: label,
                // Or use the 'icon' property.
                withText: true,
                tooltip: true
            } );

            view.on( 'execute', () => {
                if ( action === 'paste' ) {
                    alert( 'Sorry man, no can do!' );
                } else {
                    document.execCommand( action );
                }
            } );

            return view;
        } );
    }
}

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Essentials, Paragraph, ClipboardButtons ],
        toolbar: [
            'copy', 'cut', 'paste'
        ]
    } )
    .then( editor => {
    } )
    .catch( err => {
        console.error( err.stack );
    } );
```

You can read more about implementing plugins in the CKEditor 5 Framework's [Quick Start guide](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html).

You should achieve something like this:

[image: Screenshot of CKEditor 5 with copy/cut/paste buttons]

Comment: That example is for classic, not balloon.