# Angular 15 CKEditor 5 config toolbar

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I want to have a CKEditor with this toolbar in my angular app

[image]

I tried

```json
config = { toolbar: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'PasteText', '|', 'Undo', 'Redo', '|', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike' , 'superscript', 'subscript', '|', 'link' ] }
```

```html
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="config" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

Output

[image]

I also tried using [Toolbar Configurator](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/toolbarconfigurator/)

Got this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
        { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
        { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'Source,Save,Templates,NewPage,Preview,Print,Paste,PasteFromWord,Replace,Find,SelectAll,Scayt,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,About,Maximize,ShowBlocks,BGColor,TextColor,Styles,Format,Font,FontSize,Iframe,PageBreak,SpecialChar,HorizontalRule,Table,Flash,Unlink,Anchor,Image,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,JustifyRight,Language,JustifyBlock,JustifyCenter,JustifyLeft,CreateDiv,Indent,BulletedList,NumberedList,Outdent,CopyFormatting,RemoveFormat';
};
```

I made some changes to become an object

```
config = {
    toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
        { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
        { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
    ],

    removeButtons: 'Source,Save,Templates,NewPage,Preview,Print,Paste,PasteFromWord,Replace,Find,SelectAll,Scayt,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,About,Maximize,ShowBlocks,BGColor,TextColor,Styles,Format,Font,FontSize,Iframe,PageBreak,SpecialChar,HorizontalRule,Table,Flash,Unlink,Anchor,Image,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,JustifyRight,Language,JustifyBlock,JustifyCenter,JustifyLeft,CreateDiv,Indent,BulletedList,NumberedList,Outdent,CopyFormatting,RemoveFormat'
}
```

Output Default Toolbar

Comment: have you tried [online-builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder) ?

Comment: @Dorota *Yes*, but still didn't work, IDK if I'm missing some additional libraries, I followed [the docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/frameworks/angular.html) & it should run fine. No clue...

Comment: for cut/copy/paste this might be helpful -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50735840/3463202